# Shortest distance between factors without using array, data structures or any api in java?

Tags: java

I was asked a question to find a shortest distance between factors of a number without using arrays, any data structures or string in Java. For example if 13013 is passed to a method it should return 2, since the factors of 13013 are 1*7*11*13*13 and the shortest distance between two different number is 13-11=2, one more example if 10 is passed it should return 1, since factors of 10 are 1*2*5 and the shortest distance is (2-1) which is 1. What i found was if even number is passed it should always return 1, since 2, and 1 is always involved in the factor and (2-1)=1, if prime is passed it will be (number-1), since prime is only divisible by itself and 1, and if odd is passed mostly it is 2 Since (3-1)=2, but I am not being able to find for all numbers.

This is what I have till this point, thank you all

```
static int findDistance(int numberPassed)
{   
    boolean isPrime=true;
    int returnValue=0;

    if(numberPassed % 2==0)
    {   
        //If it is even there must be 2 and 1 as a factor therefore 2-1=1
        returnValue=1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=2;i<numberPassed;i++)
        {
            if(numberPassed % i==0)
            {   
                //if number is divisible by any except by 1 and itself
                //it is prime 
                isPrime=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime && numberPassed!=1)
        {   
            //If it is prime then return value should be numberPassed-1
            //since factor of prime are 1 and itself, so shortest distance
            //numberPassed-1
            returnValue=numberPassed-1;
        }
        else
        {   
            //The problem is here if the number is not prime and is odd
            //since shortest distance differes now, for value divisible by 3 
            //it should be 3-1=2, but there are many other cases
            returnValue=2;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: So what's the *actual* problem? We're not a homework or schoolwork dumping ground and we won't help those who don't put in any effort and *show* it

Comment: The problem is a clean and smart code, that finds a shortest distance between factors, thank you.

Comment: @Hendrix333 no, that's what you want, on a plate, without effort on your part beyond writing the question into SO. *What's stopping you doing it yourself?*

Comment: I am just looking for logic I do not need somebody to write me a code, thanks.

Comment: Mr Andy Turner, like I have mentioned in my post, I found out that even number always return 1 as shortest distance, prime returns number-1, I am stuck in odd numbers which mostly returns 2, but not always.Thanks

Comment: Show your code so far.

Comment: There is no logic behind that: for 77 it's 4 (1*7*11), for 1387 it's 18 (1*19*73) and so on. You always can take arbitrary primes, multiply them and therefore get arbitrary distances. So there is no smart algorithm behind that. And the sure way is a computationally hard one...

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle, so what is the hard way, the issue is saving the factors, and since arrays, arraylist , or any data structures is not allowed, how to manipulate the factors and find the shortest distance. Thanks

Comment: Well, finding the factors is the hard thing. You don't need an array, arraylist or anything like that. Only two `int`s - one for the shortest distance so far, one for the last factor. Find the next factor, compare, that's it. Coding that is your work. Note that there is no smart algorithm - you need to know the factors and there is no much better way than trying every (prime) number up to the square root of your input.

Comment: Thank you @TobiasBrösamle, indeed there is not smart algorithm, and the logic you mention works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static int findDistance(int a)
{   
    //variables needed for calculation 
    int temp=a;
    int fact=1;
    int distance=0;
    int shortestDistance=a;
    int lastFact=1;

    while(temp>1)
    {   
        //If value is divisible by fact variable
        if(temp % fact==0)
        {   
            //If last fact does not equal current fact
            if(lastFact!=fact)
            {
            distance=fact-lastFact;
            lastFact=fact;
            }
            //divide by fact
            temp=temp/fact;

            //reassign the fact to 1 so that it can start from beginning
            fact=1;

            //if distance is not zero and shortestDistance is bigger
            if(shortestDistance>distance && distance !=0)
            {   
                //now the shortest distance is the distance
                shortestDistance=distance;
            }
        }

        fact++;
    }
    return shortestDistance;
}
```

Comment: Starting agaim drin zur beginning will give you no more information, so it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int minDistance(int num){
        int fact1 = 1;
        int minDist = num;
        int fact2 = 0;
        for(int i=2; i<num; i++){
            if (num%i==0){
            fact2 = i;
                if((fact2-fact1)<=minDist){
                    minDist = fact2-fact1;
                    fact1 = fact2;                   
                }           
            }
        }
    return (minDist);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + minDistance(1001));
    }

    public static int minDistance(int n) {
        int minDistance = n;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if (n % i == 0 && n % j == 0) {
                    if (i > j) {
                        int distance = i - j;
                        if (distance < minDistance) {
                            minDistance = distance;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return minDistance;
    }
}
```

> Here,two for-loops are used: **Outer for-loop** is used to take one value at a time and calculate distance between two value(Second value is obtained from **Inner for-loop**) and stored in **distance** variable. Since minimum distance between the factors of the number will always be less than itself, so the **minDistance** is initialized to the number itself. If the distance is less than minDistance value then minDistance is reset to new distance value.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!!! Will look into it to help for future readers.